# Textarea appears when I click on a button

Tags: html

I am trying to make a textarea appear when I click on a button because I don't need it to be displayed by itself in my html page.
I'm using something like:

```
<textarea cols = "50" rows = "20" name="text" id="text_id" class="form-control" style="resize:vertical" ></textarea>
```

But this is not resolving my problem.

Any idea how I can do that?

I actually have two textarea that display the content of existing files, and when I click on a button to show the content in one text area and then click on the second button to show the content of the second textarea, the first textarea becomes empty while I need to keep both contents in both textareas displayed at the same time! How can I do that too?

Comment: I do not think that is possible without javascript

Comment: This is not possible without any javascript. It is possible with just a few lines though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery already, you might do something like this:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="20" name="text" id="text_id" class="form-control" style="resize:vertical;display:none"></textarea>
<button class="show_button">Show/hide textarea</button>
<script>$(".show_button").click(function(){$("#text_id").toggle()})</script>
```

This will toggle the textarea for showing

I'm just assuming you're using jQuery, since `form-control` is used with Bootstrap - That requires jQuery.

Comment: This doesn't really work, it shows me the text area for like a second and then it disappears again.

Comment: my original code for the button is this <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="Run"  > I changed for what you said and it doesnt work anymore. @Frederik Spang

Comment: You'll need an id, or class to identify it. What it it, that doesn't work? Try posting your actual code, then!

Comment: Here is my code <form action="/test_users"  method="post" >    
         <div class="form-inline">
         <textarea cols = "50" rows = "20" name="testid" id="test_id" class="form-control" style="resize:vertical" >{{ f }}</textarea> 
      <br>
     
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="Run"  onclick="var a = document.getElementById('test_id').value" >
     
     </div>
     
    </form>

Comment: The code I've provided should just toggle, on the click. Try changing toggle() to show(), then.

Comment: Same thing, just shows up for not even a second and disapears. here is what I did <form action="/test_users"  method="post" >    
         <div class="form-inline">
        <td> <textarea cols = "50" rows = "20" name="testid" id="test_id" class="form-control" style="resize:vertical;display:none" >{{ f }}</textarea> 
      <br>
    </td>
     <td> <input class="btn-primary" type="submit"  value="Suspended Users" onclick="var a = document.getElementById('susp_id').value" > </td>
<script>$(".btn-primary").click(function(){$("#text_id").show()})</script>
     
     </div>
     
    </form>

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple javascript or even jquery. But for simple javascript u can do it like this:
On script tag inside head section write:

```
 <script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<textarea cols = '50' rows = '20' name='text' id='text_id' class='form-control' style='resize:vertical' ></textarea>";
}
</script>
```

On Body section :

```
<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Can do it without using any javascript?

Comment: did u copy pasted the code that i wrote. because it had worked when i did the same. So i recommend u to copy paste the code in script tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea cols = '50' rows = '20' name='text' id='text_id' class='form-control' style='resize:vertical; visibility:hidden'> </textarea>

<button onClick='document.getElementById("text_id").style.visibility = "visible" '> Click me !</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most compact way you can do this I can think of:

We are giving the Textarea a CSS property to stay hidden Display = 'none'.
Once the button is clicked, it changes that css property to Display = 'block' to make it visible.

```
<textarea cols = "50" rows = "20" name="text" id="text_id" class="form-control" style="resize:vertical; display = 'none'"></textarea>
<button onclick = "document.getElementById('text_id').style.display = 'block'">
```